# Why can't I remove this trim board?

Tags: deck, exterior, trim

I'm re-surfacing our deck. On one section where it meets the house, this piece of 1x12 trim had rotted a way on the bottom where it met the deck. I believe it is cedar, which is what the rest of the deck is. I'm replacing the deck with TimberTech composite. Also was planning on replacing this trim board with a PVC composite, due to this piece rotting. But now I'm stuck because I can't get this trim out. I've pulled out the nails, but it seems to be somehow anchored within this piece of metal above it that it is tucked in to. I tried bending it and even tore out a small section. But that didn't loosen the trim board at all. I also wonder if it's tied in to the trim on the right. That's the trim on a screened in porch. Where this trim meets that trim, that trim is somewhat rotted as well.

One of the installers from the deck store came out to give me some tips. On this rotted trim board that I'm trying to remove, he said that piece of metal above it might be some kind of flashing or rain guard, to try to keep the water out, and that I might want to keep it, if I can.

It looks like this 'rain guard'/flashing, is tied in or secured by the vertical cedar siding above it. I hope that's not the case, because I don't want this to turn into an even bigger job. Any ideas or suggestions?

[image: trim board]

[image: trim drip guard?]

Comment: That metal is indeed flashing. And yes it most assuredly binds up behind the upper siding. Do you best to not remove it if you can.

Answer (score 1):

The z flashing probably has a good pinch on the top of that 1x12. Also dried paint likely has bonded to the surface

[image]
Try to get a thin putty knife worked under the lip to separate the flashing from the trim board. 
Be aware that your idea for a new trim board will only work if the new one is same thickness as the old one. 
Try to avoid deforming the z flashing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as you can see, it's a bit late to avoid deforming the z flashing (sad emoji here)

Comment: You can ask a new question for ideas on how to fix this area. How long is the section you will be replacing? It is possible to carefully remove a section of the flashing and fit in a new piece. There are other ways to make a waterproof repair. Ask and I’ll bet you get some good suggestions.